# How to hide views search filters on results page with quicktabs

Tags: search, blocks

How to hide views search filters on results page with quicktabs I would like to have the search fields hidden when a user clicks on apply on the advanced tab.

Is there a way to do this?

I can get this done with setting exposed filters form to yes, but it doesn't work in quicktabs.

This site in question is:

http://www.vuxi.com

Comment: Allow me to ask how you presented such filter options array in the first place?

Comment: Not sure what array means...but these are exposed filters in views

Comment: I want this search:

http://imagebin.ca/v/29vyg9Y15mcv

To display results, but not search fields:


http://imagebin.ca/v/29vyrhmAHHEJ